How to config bundler for React Native with Expo to ignore .native files and pick the right one
I am using React Native with Expo (51.0.8).
I have an error reported by the web bundle when using PagerView:
 Unable to resolve module ../Utilities/Platform

I have tried to divide my component into
introduction.native.tsx
introduction.tsx
But it seems that the web bundle pick the introduction.native.tsx anyway, because it still gives me the same error.
babel.config.js:
module.exports = function (api) {
api.cache(true);
 return {
   presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
   plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
 };
};

This is my introduction.native.tsx code:
    return (
    <SafeAreaView testID='safe-area-view' style={styles.flex}>
        {Platform.OS === "web" ? (
            <RestyleBox>
                <RestyleText>This is the web</RestyleText>
            </RestyleBox>
        ) : (
            <PagerView
                testID='pager-view'
                initialPage={0}
                // ref={ref}
                style={styles.PagerView}
                // onPageScroll={onPageScroll}
            >
                {data.map((d) => (
                    <IntroScreen
                        title={d.title}
                        key={d.key}
                        SvgComponent={d.SvgComponent}
                        description={d.description}
                        ExtraComponent={
                            d.ExtraComponent === undefined ? <></> : d.ExtraComponent()
                        }
                    />
                ))}
            </PagerView>
        )}

        <View style={styles.dotsContainer}>
            <View style={styles.dotContainer}>
                <SlidingDot
                    testID={"sliding-dot"}
                    marginHorizontal={3}
                    data={data}
                    //@ts-ignore
                    scrollX={scrollX}
                    dotSize={12}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
);

}
If i comment PagerView component, there is no error anymore. But still, how can I fix my config, or what is wrong, so that metro does not pick only the introduction.tsx file for the bundle.
This is how I access my introduction component
                <AppButton
                variant='filled'
                title='Login'
                onPress={() => {
                    console.log("TODO FETCH LOGIN");
                    router.navigate("/introduction");
                }}
            ></AppButton>


I'm running into the same issue. Did you find any solution?
